# Centos: Package Managed Sun JRE

Tags: centos, yum, sun, java

Is there no yum repository with Sun's JRE available (don't really need the JDK)? From looking around everyone simply recommends manually downloading and installing the binary that Sun/Oracle provides. Used to it being managed in a Debian/Ubuntu environment. I do know the OpenJDK implementation is available in the repos.

I'm guessing the reason it isn't in any of the default repos is because Sun's implementation isn't truly "free" software. Just surprised it's not in any other repo as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent quite some time on the same subject. I believe the reason is it is not legal to redistribute these files in this fashion.

I eventually just put together a small local repository on one of my VMs and used the createrepo command to bundle up the RPM files that Sun provides. Then it is just a matter of adding the new repo to your yum config. It provides an easy way for me to update all my tomcat instances at once.

Comment: There might be legal issues, but the Sun implementations are available in other distributions (like Debian and Ubuntu) in non-free or partner repositories (which are not managed by Sun). Managing it myself does seem to be the next best solution.

Comment: @Nicholi No longer.  They've ended the distributor licensing as of the Java 7 release; expect those who still offer it in a repository to stop doing so in the next release cycle or two.  See sysadmin1138's post on the subject [here](http://sysadmin1138.net/mt/blog/2011/09/opensuse-and-java.shtml).